# How to Insert Data To PostgreSQL With Stored Procedure in NiFi ExecuteSQL

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I'm fairly new on both Apache NiFi and PostgreSQL.
I'm trying to insert data into my PostgreSQL table with ExecuteSQL processor in Nifi.
The steps are like this:

1. I'm getting data from MSSQL (this part is okey)
2. Then I use SplitAvro processor (this part is okey)
3. Then I'm using ExecuteSQL processor and I'm writing my PostgreSQL stored procedure into select query part in the configuration. But I'm getting "Unable to execute sql select query, xxx column does not exit." But the table and columns are in the Postgres.
   I've controlled my controller service for postre connection, it's okey. I've used "" for column names.
   By the way the column names are the same in both mssql and postgre.
   I couldn't find any proper way to handle this problem.
   Is there anyone to help me about this issue?
   Thanks.

Comment: Show the parameters of execute sql.